# Java - specify the IP to run from

Tags: java

I have a server with 2 IPs (example: 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2) and a Java process that I want to run. The servers default IP is what it runs from if I start it, but I want the process to run from the secondary IP.

Is this possible *without* create virtual machines and running from inside those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a program that you wrote yourself, assuming you are doing some sort of binding on a [ServerSocket](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/), you can specify the address to listen to when you call the bind() method.

If this is a process that you did not write, then you'd have to consult the documentation to see if the author's offer a way to configure which address is used.